# SOQL Query help with more than one level of relationships

Tags: soql, query

I'm looking to run a query from a custom object (called RS) related to Case (Master Detail) where I need to get a list of the contacts related to the Account on the Case.

I can run the following query from the case and get the information, but I need to the get the same information running it from the RS child object:

```
SELECT Name, Id
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case where id = '500XXXX')
```

I think it would look something like this:

```
select name, (select Name, id from Contact) from account where id IN (select Case.AccountId from RS__c where id = 'a1234XXX')
```

but get the error "inner select field cannot have more than one level of relationships"

Is it even possible to get this info with one query?

Answer (score 3):

You say that your `RS` object is in a Master-Detail relationship with `Case`. Assuming that `RS` is the detail side of the relationship, you simply need to loop over your `RS` records and gather the related `Case` Ids.

With that, you should be able to run your query with one small change.

```java
// Declare either a set or a list to hold the Ids.
// It doesn't really matter which one, my preference is for a Set though.
Set<Id> caseIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
for(RS__c rsRec :myRsRecordList){
    // I'm assuming the relationship field is Case__c
    // Even though the relationship field will show you the name of the related
    //   record in Visualforce (guessing the same is true for Lightning), the field, in
    //   reality, holds the Id of the related record.
    caseIdsSet.add(rsRec.Case__c);
}

List<Contact> contactsList = [SELECT Name, Id
                              FROM Contact
                              WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT AccountId
                                                  FROM Case
                                                  // This is the small change to your query
                                                  WHERE Id IN :caseIdsSet
                                                 )];
```

If this code is part of a trigger on your `RS` object, then this is the only query that you'll need. If you're not doing this as part of a trigger (or otherwise don't have access to the Trigger context variables), then you will need another query to grab the required field(s) from your object.

#### +edit:

So you're outside of a trigger context. In that case, there's only one way I can think of the avoid the second query; use a formula field.

#### Update to edit:

formula fields can't be used in semijoins. There is still merit in the example below, but to use it in your situation, you'd still likely need to query `RS__c` records to obtain the value of the formula field (and then you'd be using code based on my first example).

If you have a formula field that pulls down the `AccountId` from the `Case` your `RS` record is related to, you could use that in your semi-join like so...

```java
List<Contact> contactsList = [SELECT Name, Id
                              FROM Contact
                              WHERE AccountId IN
                                  (SELECT Account_Id_Formula__c 
                                   FROM RS__c
                                   WHERE Id IN :myRSRecordsList
                                  )
                          ];
```

While the most common use of a semijoin is where you'd query the object whose Ids you're trying to obtain (i.e. `Account` in this case), it'll work on *any* object provided that you have a field that holds the appropriate Id on that object (I don't believe you're allowed any hierarchy traversal, up or down, in a semijoin).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, but this wouldn't be running from a trigger. Is it a limitation in SOQL where this information can't be pulled from one query?

Comment: @CarlosF Pretty much, yeah. You can only have one level of sub-queries (so `WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id IN (SELECT Case__c FROM RS__c ...))` won't work). You can traverse up to 5 levels upwards in a hierarchy, but only one level down a hierarchy. Thus, to get information about `Contacts`, you either need to query the `Contact` object itself, or `SELECT Id, (SELECT ... FROM Contacts) FROM Account ...`. `RS` is two levels down the hierarchy from `Account`, and not directly related to `Contact`, so 2 queries are required.

Comment: @CarlosF About the only way I can think of possibly avoiding a second query, even outside of a trigger context, would be to create a formula field. I'll edit my answer to elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and examples! I tried using the formula field and get the error "semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use IDformula__c". Perhaps I can try to create a relationship between the account and the custom object, so that it will only be one level relationship.

Comment: @CarlosF I suppose that's what I get for suggesting something without trying it myself first. Having a direct relationship between `Account` and `RS__c` would allow you to only use a single query (though you'll need something like a trigger to populate that lookup, so I'm not sure that's much better).

Comment: Eureka! @DerekF I was able to get it to work creating a lookup relationship with Account and RS__c. Now I can populate the existing records with the IDs of the account using Data Loader, and use Process Builder to populate the lookup going forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the Case object, query the related object instead, and use a filter on the relationship field.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name 
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId IN (
    SELECT AccountId 
    FROM RS__c
    WHERE Case__c = '...'
)
```